# Simple way to get regionemail in second table and in body column their branch

Tags: sql-server

I have a 2 tables

First table

```
Id      branchemail                            regionemail
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.     Amar@gmail.com.                  har@gmail.com
2.     Sima@gmail.com.                   har@gmail.com
3.     Sam@gmail.com.                    mic@gmail.com
4.     Suzane@gmail.com.               mic@gmail.com
```

Second table

```
Id       regionemail       Body
--------------------------------------------
```

I would like to get regionemail in second table and in body column their branchemail

For exmaple:second table look like

```
Id   regionemail           Body
--------------------------------------------
1  har@gmail.com   Amar@gmail.com,Sima@gmail.com.
2 mic@gmail.com     Sam@gmail.com, Suzane@gmail.com
```

The above is dummy data. I have 20 regionemails and thousands of branchemail against.

Comment: Sorry,That was typos error. Chk nw

Comment: It is better to post a script that contains DDL for your tables and statements to populate them with sample data. This should include primary and foreign key constraints, since they are the key to "getting" the information you desire. And it helps to provide an example of what you desire based on your sample data.

Comment: Id column is a primary key. There is no any foreign key in this.

Comment: Any help?............

Comment: Thank you. I have resolved it by myself using xml path()